# Element binding not updating when dependency property changed

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom button control which has a dependency property "IsRequired"

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRequiredProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(IsRequired), typeof(bool), typeof(RequiredButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public bool IsRequired
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRequiredProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsRequiredProperty, value); }
    }
```

And implements an interface

```
public interface IRequiredControl
{
    bool IsEnabled { get; }
    bool IsRequired { get; }
}
```

And I have a converter that uses this interface

```
   <sharedConverters:IsRequiredToImageConverter x:Key="IsRequiredToImageConverter"
                                                 DisabledImage="{StaticResource DisabledDrawing}"
                                                 NormalImage="{StaticResource NormalDrawing}"
                                                 RequiredImage="{StaticResource IsRequiredDrawing}" />


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IRequiredControl requiredControl)
        {
            return !requiredControl.IsEnabled ? DisabledImage : requiredControl.IsRequired ? RequiredImage : NormalImage;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
```

I use the converter and bind the image source to the control, as seen below.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RightSideAddTemplate">
    <sharedControls:RequiredButton x:Name="addButton"
                                   Command="{x:Static commands:AddCommand}"
                                   IsRequired="{Binding IsButtonRequired}">
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=addButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IsRequiredToImageConverter}}" />
    </sharedControls:RequiredButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

The issue occurs here where the converter is never called when the "IsButtonRequired" viewmodel property is changed. When I set the "IsRequired" of the "AddButton" explicitly to true it works correctly. How can I make the converter update on a change to the "IsRequired" property?

**Note** I have another solution working where I use a multivalue converter, but I would prefer to get element binding solution working, because it requires much less xaml.

```
<Image Style="{StaticResource AddImageButtonStyle}">
     <Image.Source>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsRequiredToImageMultiConverter}">
               <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                     <Binding ElementName="addButton" Path="IsEnabled" />
                     <Binding Path="IsButtonRequired" />
               </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
         </Image.Source>
     </Image>
```

Comment: Does the IsButtonRequired view model property fire a change notification? As a note, setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the Image Source Binding is pointless. It has no effect at all.

Comment: Also note that a RelativeSource Binding instead of an ElementName Binding would save the need for x:Name on the RequiredButton.

Comment: Hey clemens, yes the viewmodel is working properly, I have added the multibinding code which works with the viewmodel. You're right about the UpdateSourceTrigger, and RelativeSource I will update those

Comment: That would work but it is missing then the IsEnabled state, however your suggestion to use RelativeSource instead of ElementName fixed the issue for me, I am not sure why this fixed it, but thank you. If you would like you can submit that as an answer and I will mark it as the solution

Comment: I fail to see how RelativeSource should change this. The problem is that the Binding is not supposed to be triggered when a property of the control changes. A MultiBinding is the proper way to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binding expression

```
<Image Source="{Binding ElementName=addButton,
                Converter={StaticResource IsRequiredToImageConverter}}" />
```

binds directly to the RequiredButton control, and is not supposed to be triggered when a property of the control changes.

The proper way to implement this is a MultiBinding on both the IsEnabled and IsRequired properties of the control:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsRequiredToImageMultiConverter}">
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding ElementName="addButton" Path="IsEnabled"/>
        <Binding ElementName="addButton" Path="IsRequired"/>
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
</MultiBinding>
```

The multi-value converter would have to test two boolean values.

---

Alternatively to using a MultiBinding, a Style with a set of MultiTriggers would also work:

```
<Style TargetType="sharedControls:RequiredButton">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource DisabledDrawing}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
                <Condition Property="IsRequired" Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource NormalDrawing}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
                <Condition Property="IsRequired" Value="true" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource IsRequiredDrawing}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```